# PowerShell Retrieve file name and path

Tags: powershell

So, what I need is from my registry editor retrieve the name and path of the file I'm right clicking to pass it as an argument to a python file.

I already have some code to create the right click shortcut to run my python script.

The code I'm having trouble with is this one:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path $commandKey -Name '(default)' -Value "cmd /C `"C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\ipy.exe`" `"$scriptPython`" `"%1`" `"%V`""
```

I have tried changing "%1" and "%V" with the name and file and it works, so my .py code is correct
.

Answer (score 0):

So, what is the issue? And shouldn't you replace `%1` and `%V` with Powershell variables?